# Rscript -e not working on windows

Tags: r, windows, bash, cygwin

On a cygwin installed windows 7 box, I opened a bash prompt and executed the below :

```
`$Rscript -e 'rownames(installed.packages())'`
`[1] "devtools"     "SparkR"       "Transformers" "base"         "boot"
[6] "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"    "compiler"     "datasets"
[11] "foreign"      "graphics"     "grDevices"    "grid"             "KernSmooth"
[16] "lattice"      "MASS"         "Matrix"       "methods"      "mgcv"
[21] "nlme"         "nnet"         "parallel"     "rpart"            "spatial"
[26] "splines"      "stats"        "stats4"       "survival"     "tcltk"
[31] "tools"        "translations" "utils"`

`$ `Rscript -e ' if("devtools" %in% installed.packages()) { library(devtools); print ("hi") }'`
```

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'devtools' not found
>   Calls: %in% -> match
>   Execution halted`

or

```
`$ `Rscript -e ' if(is.element("devtools", installed.packages()[,1]) == TRUE) { library(devtools); print ("hi") }'`
```

> Error in match(el, set, 0L) : object 'devtools' not found
>   Calls: is.element -> match
>   Execution halted`

Any idea what i am missing to get the if condition working properly.
Everything above works properly in a R script or Rstudio on windows.

Also i do not see any problem with the if conditions with `Rscript -e` on linux operating system. So something looks very non-obvious on windows.

Comment: Weird. I don't have a windows machine nearby so can't test. But as a first guess there is something going on with `"` interpretation. Did you try changing all the double quotes to single quotes inside that line (and single quotes to double quotes after -e) ?

Comment: What’s with the backticks around the commands and output?

Comment: yes, unclear about back-tics. Also, is the `$` meant to be the prompt char? Best to leave out anything that complicates a readers ability to copy/paste directly from your Q.Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output/ErrMsgs. 
 Good luck.

Comment: Works for me: `[1] "hi"`, after installing devtools. Are you using cygwin R or windows version ?